# Is pure RESTful required for Angular JS / Backend running on same web server?

Tags: design, rest, angularjs

I am developing an application with Sprintboot + REST + Angular. While I am working on the REST API, I am trying to design as RESTful as possible. I'm encountering certain pages where the Angular UI must send multiple requests to the service to display the page like a User Approval page. I'm worried this would slow down the application or create complexity in Angular code base. Should I just have an end point /orderapproval that would do every thing related to order approval functionality or have bunch of APIs that need to be called for like /order /inventory /user etc. It is awful to consider /orderapproval as a REST API. But is it acceptable to just work as an API for applications that have both Back End and UI running in same web server.

Comment: Not sure if complete duplicate of http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/224373/creating-rest-ful-web-services-without-adhering-to-the-rest-principles but trying to read more minds as Angular has developed in last 2 years.

Comment: I think the crux of this problem comes down to the following statement: _"I am trying to design as RESTful as possible"_ Can you explain _why_ that is? The answer to your question is likely follow on from your explanation.

Comment: Just in a hypothetical situation when I've to expose the API to a third party who want to construct their own UI.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly. No, a pure RESTful web service is not required for an angularjs app. It will work just fine with more RPC like interfacing also.

I would never recommend anyone to pursue pure RESTfulness, especially the HATEOAS part is just a waste of time and effort. Noone will work with your API that dynamically. Until you have concrete requirements in this area I would stay far away from it.

I prefer a 'back-end for front-end' strategy, if you need a 'orderapproval' resource cause it would help reduce the amount of chatting with the back-end that would be more then fine.

Building one web app and simultaneously a 'generic general purpose Web API' is a really hard thing to do, I typically recommend customers against this strategy.

The general purpose Web API is really something you should look at separately or something that could emerge after your 3rd app using a common interface.

Comment: Thank you for making this comment. Would have done it this way if it were 6 months earlier. Already halfway in the project and decided to do RESTful as much as possible and doing RPC like interface wherever it gets complex.